# How to store user activity history

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm being told this question is subjective, but hey ho.

Am I best storing user activity in a table in a mysql database or in an xml file. The aim is for the data to be printed on their account page.

I'm worried that I will either end up with a huge/slow database or many many xml files on the server (one for each user).

Thanks

Comment: Consider this - it is really difficult to ever query the XML files as a unit to discover aggregate patterns across users. You may only intend right now to display it on their account pages, but if you store it in XML it will never be useful for anything but that.  Put it in a database, index it where appropriate, and it won't be slow.

Comment: Please include more details about your use case: number of users, activity details stored, how long records have to persist, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in a table. If you're storing billions of records you'll want to investigate partitioning or sharding, but those are problems you should tackle if and only if you will be hitting limits.

Test any design you have by simulating enough user activity to represent a year or two worth of vigorous use. If it holds up, you're okay. If not you'll have specific problems to address.

Remember in tables of this sort having indexes is important for retrieval speed, but too many indexes can slow down inserts. There's a balance here between too much and too little indexing you'll have to find.

XML files are often extremely expensive to append to unless you do something like what [Adium did with their reverse XML parser](https://trac.adium.im/wiki/LMXParser) built to append to XML logs efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DB of some sort. Files may have issues regarding I/O, locking, concurrent access and so on. 
If you do use files, prefer json over xml.
For RDMS, Mysql is fine. 
I would suggest using a NOSQL, my choice would be Redis.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it should be on the DB.

1) As it would be much easier to maintain a Database table for log information than separate log files.  not much load on the server.

2) for `RDBMS` you need to query for those user log history which would be hard for the xml files

3) Proper indexing will help for faster data retrieval.

4) XML read/write cost more I/O OP